# Selecting the first of 3n+1 elements from an xpath

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors

How can I implement a selection based on selecting the first 3n+1 elements from a tag in it's path? For example, let's say I have the following xpath:

```
//div[@class='ResultsSectionContainer-sc-gdhf14-0 kteggz']/div[@class='Wrapper-sc-11673k2-0 gIBPSk']//div/div/a
```

Taken from this url:

```
https://www.jobsite.co.uk/jobs?page=2&action=paging_next.html
```

Which selects the @href from each `a` tag. This website is dynamic, so I would need something that can generalise the path. However, for every three tags, two I do not need. Hence, I require all those hrefs belonging to 3n+1 selections when n = 0,1, 2, ...

Is there a way to implement this?

For example, the total number of hrefs I can select is 75, therefore I'm looking for 25 elements as 75/3 = 25, as we divide by the leading coefficient.

Can a selection like this be done in python? Otherwise, given a general selection:

```
a*n+c
```

How can I implement a selection like this when selecting for xpaths?

Although, if an easier alternative is available in selecting those href's from the url is also appreciated as I can only think of this way. Though, I presume this method can generalise more over different urls.

If there's a CSS-selector version, that would also be appreciated!

Comment: Css-selector `nth-child(An+B)` exists: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Also there are `nth-of-type` and negative (`nth-last-of-type`, `nth-last-child`) selectors with same signature. Note that `n` here refers to literal letter `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath filter predicate `[position() mod 3 = 1]` selects all elements whose 1-based position is 3n+1 for some integer n.

Comment: How do I use the `position` argument? I have tried this with the website url: ```//body//div//div[@data-at='unified-resultlist']//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//article//div//div//a[position() mod 3 = 1]``` however, it still selects the 75?

Comment: All that `//div//div//div` stuff looks terrible, and almost certainly redundant, but I'm not going to visit the HTML page to work out its structure for myself. You probably need parentheses somewhere to get it right: remember that `div//a[position()=X]` doesn't mean the same as `(div//a)[position()=X]`. Try reducing it to a simpler problem that we can all understand more easily.

Comment: Yes, you're right! this short path works just the same: ```//article//div//div//a ```, however I still cannot get the position as wanted, how might I want to think about this?

Comment: Ah brilliant! I had to implement the position argument much earlier and change the mod. It works successfully now with: ```//article//div//div[position() mod 7 = 6]/a```

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is to use a **correct** locator.
I guess you are trying to get all the job links?
If so, instead of this
`//div[@class='ResultsSectionContainer-sc-gdhf14-0 kteggz']/div[@class='Wrapper-sc-11673k2-0 gIBPSk']//div/div/a`
very long, complex and fragile XPath you can use this XPath:

```py
//a[@data-at='job-item-title']
```

In case you still need to select from the list some specific elements matching some locator you can collect all these elements into the list with `driver.find_elements_by_whatever` and then to iterate over this list in a loop with condition you need.